# Props "Object is possibly 'undefined'" in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to Typescript and I have an error I don't understand in React Typescript. I suspect that it comes from the way I write my interface but I am not sure.

First I call my CellEditable component

```js
<CellEditable value={'Hello'} onChange={() => {}} />
```

CEllEditable has an `isEditable` state that toggles InputText on click

**CellEditable.tsx**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Cell from './Cell.comp'
import InputText from './InputText.comp'

interface CellEditableProps {
  value: string
  onChange?: () => void
}

const renderCellInput = (type: string, opts: any) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'text':
      return <InputText {...opts} />
    default:
      return <div>Missing!</div>
  }
}

const CellEditable = (props: CellEditableProps) => {
  const { value, onChange } = props
  const [isEditing, setEditing] = useState<boolean>(false)

  const handleClick = () => setEditing(!isEditing)
  const handleBlur = () => setEditing(!isEditing)

  const opts = {
    value,
    helpers: {
      onBlur: handleBlur,
      onChange
    }
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      {
        isEditing
        ? renderCellInput('text', opts)
        : <Cell value={value} />
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default CellEditable
```

**InputText.tsx**

```js
import React from 'react'

interface InputTextProps {
  value?: string
  helpers?: HelpersProps
}

interface HelpersProps {
  onChange?: () => void
  onBlur?: () => void
}

const InputText = (props: InputTextProps) => {
  const { value, helpers } = props
  console.log('propsInputText:', props) // Empty object in the console
  
  return (
    <input type={'text'} value={value} onChange={helpers.onChange} onBlur={helpers.onBlur} />
  )
}

export default InputText
```

The issue is:

1. `helpers.onChange` gets this error "*Object is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2532*"
2. console.log('propsInputText:', props) in InputText.tsx output an empty object.

Is it an issue with typescript and the way I write my interface?

Comment: Moving `onChange` and `onBlur` into `InputTextProps` and removing the `helpers` object seems to works. But 1) The issue doesn't happen in a CodeSandbox environment, only in my local react typescript environment 2) I would prefer to pass handlers into a container object in props 3) I want to better understand how TS interface and optional props work.

Comment: A previous answer that has been deleted suggested to test for the existence of `OnChange` and `onBlur` keys in the helpers object like so `helpers!.onChange`.  How about destructuring the helpers props: `const { value, helpers: { onChange, onBlur } } = props`. I get the following error `Property 'onChange' does not exist on type 'HelpersProps | undefined'.ts (2339)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `helpers` property in `InputTextProps` and the `onChange` property in your `HelpersProps` are optional. either make them required by removing the question mark or assign to them a default values when destructuing.

```
const { value, helpers = {} } = props;
const { onChange = () => {} } = helpers;

 return (
    <input type={'text'} value={value} onChange={onChange} onBlur={helpers.onBlur} />
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your interface:

```
interface CellEditableProps {
  value: string
  onChange?: () => void
}
```

you placed a `?` after `onChange`, that tells the compiler that it can be not passed and hence you get `"Object is possibly 'undefined'`

To remedy this solution either you can use `onChange` with `!` like `onChange!`. This thells compiler that you are sure that `onChange` will not be null. But this is a bad approach.

What you should do is check if it is not `null` or `undefined` and then proceed:

```
if(onChange) {
    ...do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your interface declaration clearly states that these can indeed be undefined (`?` marks these properties as optional). You'll need to check for their existance or fill them.

```js
const value = props.value || '';
const helpers = {
   onChange: () => {},
   onBlur: () => {},
   ...(props.helpers || {}),
};

return (
    <input type={'text'} value={value} onChange={helpers.onChange} onBlur={helpers.onBlur} />
)
```

or similar.